# Time trigger in C

Tags: c, time, eventtrigger

Is it possible to create something like a trigger in C which calls a method, say every five seconds? It would even be better if the timer goes on while the method is being carried out.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784136/simple-signals-c-programming-and-alarm-function).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [alarm() function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html) , but it's not available on all platforms (Windows for example).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
long thresh = 5*1000; //mlliseconds
//Implement getcurTime()
int prev_time = getcurTime() - thresh;

while(1){

    //Time Elapsed ?
    if (getcurTime() - prev_time >= thresh){
        prev_time = getcurTime();
        Myfunction();
    }
    Sleep(thresh);
}
```

Comment: what happened to the standard `time()` function?

Comment: @Jocke may be, but need some way to get number of seconds.

Comment: @POW You have all the seconds you need. `time()` returns the number of seconds passed since 1 January 1970.

Comment: Sleep will wait until tresh time has elapsed. But if `Myfunction` has taken more time than usual, how can I shorten the waiting time?