# C: SIGALRM - alarm to display message every second

Tags: c, alarm

So I'm trying to call an alarm to display a message "still working.." every second.
I included signal.h.

Outside of my main I have my function: (I never declare/define s for int s)

```
void display_message(int s);   //Function for alarm set up
void display_message(int s) {
     printf("copyit: Still working...\n" );
     alarm(1);    //for every second
     signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
}
```

Then, in my main

```
while(1)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
    alarm(1);     //Alarm signal every second.
```

That's in there as soon as the loop begins. But the program never outputs the 'still working...' message. What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you, ver much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784136/simple-signals-c-programming-and-alarm-function

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Signal handlers are not supposed to contain "business logic" or make library calls such as `printf`. See C11 §7.1.4/4 and its footnote:

> Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.

All the signal handler should do is set a flag to be acted upon by non-interrupt code, and unblock a waiting system call. This program runs correctly and does not risk crashing, even if some I/O or other functionality were added:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t print_flag = false;

void handle_alarm( int sig ) {
    print_flag = true;
}

int main() {
    signal( SIGALRM, handle_alarm ); // Install handler first,
    alarm( 1 ); // before scheduling it to be called.
    for (;;) {
        sleep( 5 ); // Pretend to do something. Could also be read() or select().
        if ( print_flag ) {
            printf( "Hello\n" );
            print_flag = false;
            alarm( 1 ); // Reschedule.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can typically call non-signal-safe functions if you can _guarantee_ they can't be normally called by your process (directly or indirectly). `signal` and `alarm` are both signal safe, so as long as the program does not otherwise call any signal-unsafe functions in constructors/destructors, shared libraries, 
or other threads, the program in question is actually perfectly safe.

"signal-unsafe" indicates a function *can* be unsafe, not that it *is*, and the "you can only set a `sig_atomic_t` flag" hasn't been true since POSIX.

Comment: @yyny Constructors and destructors aren't special, so you need to include the same (interrupted) thread in that list. You might find a way to do *all* I/O in a signal handler, but that's not a reasonable way to program.

Comment: `sleep()` and `alarm()` are not to be used together. So your example is not so good. The man pages in Linux mentions that issue.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Right, but only because `sleep` never actually knows what woke it up. I chose this as an example only because 1) it's the only blocking function I can just throw in without adding more dummy code, and 2) reduced delay doesn't actually break a "still working" message.

Comment: If it *is* broken, for example if you find such a message getting printed at high frequency, then the solution would be to use `usleep` to keep track of time.

Answer (score 5):

Move the calls to `signal` and `alarm` to just before your loop. Calling `alarm` over and over at high speed keeps resetting the alarm to be in one second from that point, so you never reach the end of that second!

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void display_message(int s) {
     printf("copyit: Still working...\n" );
     alarm(1);    //for every second
     signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
    alarm(1);
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
        ++n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and no luck.. What else could be causing this?

Comment: Any reason why you're calling signal again in display_message?  Once the signal is set all thats needed is another alarm call.

Comment: Although many examples show `printf()` being used in signal handlers, it's not a good idea. It probably works fine in a simple program, but as it gets more complex, it is very likely to break.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Is printf going to break because it is not reentrant or why? (showing interspersed characters is IMO not full blown breakage but inconvenience)

Comment: @PaulStelian The main problem you will notice is indeed be interspersed output. However, `printf()`  may be redirected to a file system that uses a mutex/lock mechanism and another signal happen while that lock is on... and the next signal handler tries a `printf()` of its own... and fails because the second lock generates a deadlock. More info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html

Comment: @AlexisWilke So basically yes, it's not reentrant.

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `alarm()` twice, just call it once in `main()` to initiate the callback, then once in `display_message()`.
Try this code on Linux (Debian 7.8) :

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>

void display_message(int s);   //Function for alarm set up

void display_message(int s)
{
     printf("copyit: Still working...\n" );
     alarm(1);    //for every second
     signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
    alarm(1);     // Initial timeout setting

     while (1) 
     {   
          pause();
     }   
}
```

The result will be the following one :

```
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
copyit: Still working...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `alarm()` call is for a one off signal.

To repeat an alarm, you have to call `alarm()` again each time the signal occurs.

Another issue, also, is that you're likely to get `EINTR` errors. Many system functions get interrupted when you receive a signal. This makes for much more complicated programming since many of the OS functions are affected.

In any event, the correct way to wait for the next `SIGALRM` is to use the `pause()` function. Something the others have not mentioned (instead they have tight loops, ugly!)

That being said, what you are trying to do would be much easier with a simple `sleep()` call as in:

```
// print a message every second (simplified version)
for(;;)
{
    printf("My Message\n");
    sleep(1);
}
```

and such a loop could appear in a separate thread. Then you don't need a Unix signal to implement the feat.

Note: The `sleep()` function is actually implemented using the same timer as the `alarm()` and it is clearly mentioned that you should not mix both functions in the same code.

> `sleep(3)` may be implemented using `SIGALRM`; mixing calls to `alarm()` and `sleep(3)` is a bad idea.

*(From Linux `man alarm`)*

```
void alarm_handler(int)
{
    alarm(1);    // recurring alarm
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    alarm(1);

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("My Message\n");
        // ...do other work here if needed...
        pause();
    }

    // not reached (use Ctrl-C to exit)
    return 0;
}
```

You can create variations. For example, if you want the first message to happen after 1 second instead of immediately, move the `pause()` before the `printf()`.

The "other work" comment supposes that your other work does not take more than 1 second.

It is possible to get the alarm signal on a specific thread if work is required in parallel, however, this can be complicated if any other timers are required (i.e. you can't easily share the `alarm()` timer with other functions.)

P.S. as mentioned by others, doing your `printf()` inside the signal handler is not a good idea at all.

There is another version where the `alarm()` is reset inside `main()` and the first message appears after one second and the loop runs for 60 seconds (1 minute):

```
void alarm_handler(int)
{
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    for(int seconds(0); seconds < 60; ++seconds)
    {
        alarm(1);
        // ...do other work here if needed...
        pause();
        printf("My Message\n");
    }

    // reached after 1 minute
    return 0;
}
```

Note that with this method, the time when the message will be printed is going to be skewed. The time to print your message is added to the clock before you restart the alarm... so it is always going to be a little over 1 second between each call. The other loop is better in that respect but it still is skewed. For a *perfect* (much better) timer, the `poll()` function is much better as you can specify when to wake up next. `poll()` can be used just and only with a timer. My [Snap library](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/6f2c35a2c36f5d486c53a7e65caca1af9b4ba6f3/libsnapwebsites/src/snapwebsites/snap_communicator.cpp) uses that capability (look for the `run()` function, near the bottom of the file). In 2019. I moved that one .cpp file to the [eventdispatcher](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/tree/master/eventdispatcher) library. The `run()` function is in the `communicator.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX permits certain of its functions to be called from signal handling context, the *async-signal safe* functions, search for "async-sgnal safe" [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).  (These may be understood as "system calls" rather than library calls).  Notably, this includes `write(2)`.

So you could do

```
void
display_message (int s) {
     static char const working_message [] = "copyit: Still working...\n";
     write (1, working_message, sizeof working_message - sizeof "");
     alarm(1);    /* for every second */
}
```

By the way, precise periodic alarms are better implemented using `setitimer(2)`,
since these will not be subject to drift.  Retriggering the alarm via software, as done here, will unavoidably accumulate error over time because of the time spent executing the software as well as scheduling latencies.

In POSIX `sigaction(2)` superceedes `signal(2)` for good reason:
the original Unix signal handling model was simple.  In particular,
a signal handler was reset to its original "deposition" (e.g., terminate
the process) once it was fired.  You would have to re-associate
`SIGALRM` with `display_message()` by calling `signal()` just before
calling `alarm()` in `display_message()`.

An even more important reason for using `sigaction(2)` is the
`SA_RESTART` flag.  Normally, system calls are interrupted when
a signal handler is invoked.  I.e., when then signal handler returns,
the system call returns an error indication (often -1) and `errno` is
set to `EINTR`, interrupted system call.  (One reason for this
is to be able to use `SIGALRM` to effect time outs, another is
to have a higher instance, such as a user, to "unblock" the
current process by sending it a signal, e.g.,
`SIGINT` by pressing control-C at the terminal).

In your case, you want signal handling to be transparent
to the rest of the code, so you would set the `SA_RESTART` flag
when invoking `sigaction(2)`.  This means the kernel should
restart the interrupted system call automatically.

Answer (score -1):

[ooga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542157/63743) is correct that you keep reloading the alarm so that it will never go off.  This works.  I just put a `sleep` in here so you don't keep stepping on yourself in the loop but you might want to substitute something more useful depending on where you are headed with this.

```
void display_message(int s)
{
     printf("copyit: Still working...\n" );
    // alarm(1);    //for every second
    // signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;

    while(1)
    {
        signal(SIGALRM, display_message);
        alarm(1);

        if ((ret = sleep(3)) != 0)
        {
            printf("sleep was interrupted by SIGALRM\n");
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Calling printf from a signal handler is very unsafe.

Comment: It's not unsafe in this throw-away pgm.  But fine, @vivav, don't use async-unsafe calls in a signal handler.

Comment: Really? Which is supposed to be printed first, `still working` or `sleep was interrupted`? Maybe the machine attempts to print both at the same time.

Comment: Yes, really.  The handler will run and print then sleep will return with EINTR and print.  Every single time since there is, for all intents and purposes, no chance of this demonstration program getting hit by another signal while executing the handler.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that the signal handler will run on the same thread as `main` (unless POSIX forbids OS-private threads, which I doubt), nor that sleep will wait for the handler to return first. According to the POSIX spec of sleep, any signal to the process causes an immediate return. Anyway, it's just not the right way to code.

Comment: You are reaching.  There is no guarantee that the handler will run on a particular thread *unless* it is the *only* thread or if you want to consider the chances of OP running on a system - near zero in my view - that spins up threads to handle a signal.  We agree that putting `printf` or other non-sanctioned calls in a handler is not proper coding.  But it also the easiest way to demonstrate OP's primary problem in what appears to be his first signal handling pgm without *in actuality* doing any harm.  Perhaps I was remiss in not putting in the standard disclaimer but that is all.

Comment: This is wrong because the `sleep()` may be implemented using the `SIGALRM` signal. So it won't work as you think (i.e. your alarm will likely be ignored while sleeping). It will of course be implementation independent, but on Linux if you look at the man page of `alarm` there is a warning about it.