# can't get alarm() to work more than twice

Tags: c, alarm, setjmp

```
static void AlarmHandler(int sig) ;
int i=0;
jmp_buf mark;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
 setjmp(mark);
 signal(SIGALRM, AlarmHandler); 
 alarm(2); 
 while(1);
 return 0;
}

static void AlarmHandler(int sig) { 
  signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);           
  printf("I am in AlarmHandler:  %d \n",i);
  i++;
  longjmp(mark, 0);
}
```

When I run this code the program goes through the AlarmHandler only once and then it just stays trapped inside the while loop. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Your `i` should be `volatile sig_atomic_t`. Also why are you using the `setjmp`/`longjmp` ? This can be achieved in much cleaner way...Also you are not supposed to use library functions in signal handlers.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542077/c-sigalrm-alarm-to-display-message-every-second

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is not the program I am working on. It is just the part I am having trouble with. `setjmp/longjmp` is indeed unnecessary here but I do need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program might work as you expected on some POSIXy operating systems -- in fact, it *does* work as you expected on the computer I'm typing this on.  However, it relies on a bunch of unspecified behavior relating to signals, and I think you've tripped over one of them: I think that on your computer, a signal is "blocked" — it can't be delivered again — while its handler is executing, and also, jumping out of the handler with `longjmp` does *not* unblock the signal.  So you go around the loop once and then the second SIGALRM is never delivered because it's blocked.  There are several other, related problems.

You can nail down all of the unspecified behavior and make the program reliable on all POSIXy operating systems, but you have to use different functions to set things up: [`sigsetjmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html) and [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).  You should also get rid of the busy-waiting by using [`sigsuspend`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsuspend.html) instead.  A corrected program would look something like this:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static jmp_buf mark;

static void
handle_SIGALRM(int sig)
{
  static int signal_count;

  signal_count++;
  printf("SIGALRM #%u\n", signal_count);
  siglongjmp(mark, signal_count);
}

int
main(void)
{
  sigset_t mask, omask;
  sigemptyset(&mask);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &omask)) {
    perror("sigprocmask");
    return 1;
  }

  struct sigaction sa;
  sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = 0; // DO interrupt blocking system calls
  sa.sa_handler = handle_SIGALRM;
  if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, 0)) {
    perror("sigaction");
    return 1;
  }

  if (sigsetjmp(mark, 1) >= 4)
    return 0;
  alarm(1);
  sigsuspend(&omask);

  perror("shouldn't ever get here");
  return 1;
}
```

I should probably say a few words about signal safety: In *this* program, it *is* safe to call `printf` and `siglongjmp` from the signal handler, because I have arranged for the SIGALRM *only* to be deliverable while the main thread of execution is blocked on `sigsuspend`.  (That's what the call to `sigprocmask` up top does.)  If you had anything to do in your main thread of execution *besides* sleep waiting for the signal to arrive, you would have to be [much more careful](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) about what you did in the signal handler, and I would  advocate for using [`pselect`](https://lwn.net/Articles/176911/) and/or the [self-pipe trick](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-self-pipe-trick-explained/) instead of jumping out of the handler, if at all possible.