# Signals Using Alarm() in Linux C

Tags: c

1. When there is timeout the program should move to second question and if time out it should say " your time is over ".
2. Currently my program runs for the first question but not going to second question.

I have tried many time but it doesn't work.

```
Int main(){
    int time1
    char q1[20]
    printf("\n")
    printf("Enter the malaysia capital name : ");

    alarm(30);
    scanf("%[^\n]",q1);
    
    if (time != SIGALRM)
    {
        alarm(0);
        printf("The Malaysia capital is : '%s'\n",q1);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int time2
    char q1[20]
    printf("\n")
    printf("Enter the malaysian tallest building : ");

    alarm(30);
    scanf("%s",q2);

    if (time2 != SIGALRM)
    { 
        alarm(0);
        printf("Enter the malaysian tallest building is  : '%s'\n",q2);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Expected :- After time out should move to second question
Actual :- Not moving to second question

Answer (score 1):

The `alarm()` function causes `SIGALRM` to be raised, but you have to use the [`signal()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) function first to register a handler for this signal.  Your program never registers a handler so there's nothing to run when the signal is raised.

Comment: Can someone help me

Comment: There are a number of questions on this site that have example code for using `signal()` and `alarm()`.  For example, see [either of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784136/simple-signals-c-programming-and-alarm-function) [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542077/c-sigalrm-alarm-to-display-message-every-second).