# What is the best method of implementing timer inside a thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer

I need to do some operation at regular intervals in my thread. What is the best method to do this? 
Like if, i have a local socket communication between linux deamon and a android application. In this case, if i want to send data periodically to the android app from deamon, how can i proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. See [On-topic Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: the way i used to implement this is via "select" . we can lock the while loop using the select call. we can give the timeout value in the select call and then get the timer value....

Comment: please help me to add answer for this question . i have found the answer for this.  but the question got closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux why not try `sleep()` or `usleep()` functions of `unistd.h`?

```
sleep(5);
```

Will pause the thread for five seconds and then resume execution.

---

#### `sleep(sec)`

> The `sleep()` function shall **cause the calling thread to be suspended from execution** until either the number of realtime seconds specified by the argument seconds has elapsed or a signal is delivered to the calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function or to terminate the process.

#### `usleep(usec)`

> `usleep()` function **suspends execution of the calling thread** for (at least) usec microseconds.

Emphasis mine. 
Taken from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) and [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Simple Signals - C programming and alarm function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784136/simple-signals-c-programming-and-alarm-function) if you want truely accurate timing.  If you don't do this, using `sleep()` etc will eventually result in your timer shifting due to the overhead of your code, the OS, etc.